# How to popUp image and link with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

If you know about how to do something like [this](http://eczacibasi.com.tr),
I mean how to load a javascript or jQuery popUp image onLoad (once) and how can i link it to somewhere else, please help me =(

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

```
window.onload= function(){
var myEvt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
myEvt.initEvent(
   'click'      // event type
   ,true      // can bubble?
   ,true      // cancelable?
);
document.getElementById('myLink').dispatchEvent(myEvt);

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest. But, 
1. lightbox uses "rel" attribute of a link and I need this on pageLoad     (body onload="some_function();")
2. i need image mapping, so is that possible in lightbox?
Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

here's a tutorial on how to create the modal container 
http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial 
once you have it you can trigger the modal window inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// trigger modal here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the div is just set to visible when the page loads.

```
<div id="lightBox" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1100; background:url(images/bgfb.png);display:block">
        <div  id="ekranKapla" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left:-255px; margin-top:-196px;display:block">
            <img src="/images/lightbox.png" border="" alt="facebook" useMap="#mapThis" />    
        </div>
</div>  
<map name="mapThis" id="mapThis">
<area shape="rect" coords="470,2,509,37"  onclick="javascript:lightBoxKapat();" href="#" />
<area shape="rect" coords="293,294,496,370" href="http://www.facebook.com/EczacibasiToplulugu" target="_blank" title="facebook " />
</map>

<script type="text/javascript">

function lightBoxKapat() {

    document.getElementById("lightBox").style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("ekranKapla").style.display = "none";

}
</script>
```

Then the user can click on it to hide it.

Comment: Yes I have analysed this, but when i use this, I can click the above elements in my page. For example, I can click each element of the body, while my div is open.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JavaScript for that - at least not to show it.  To have a picture displaying when the page loads, just code the HTML that way.

To show or hide it later, just use:

```
$("#popupContainer").show();
$("#popupContainer").hide();
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7rVaZ/

Comment: what if someone has javascript deactivated? then there's no way to access the rest of the site

Comment: @stratton - `<a href="pageWithoutPopupShowing.htm" onclick="$('#popup').hide(); return false;">hide</a>`.  But, seriously... who has JavaScript disabled?

Comment: Thanks gilly, but assume that I used these codes, then when page loads, it opened my div like as a popup, but still I can reach the other elements of DOM. If you look again the page which I linked, you see that you cannot click the elements of the page till you close the div by mapping method.

Comment: @enginbilici - The overlay is achieved by absolutely positioning a div that covers the entire page.  See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7rVaZ/

Comment: thank you gilly, I think this works, when I try this I will share the result here. Thank you again...